# Imageview Src path in Android in Appium

Tags: android, appium

In our Android app, we use placehold images in our thumbnails until the server returns a valid image. The Android devs change the src of the ImageView when an image is found. I am unable to find the src of the ImageView because when i do a get_attribute('src'), nothing comes up. Is there a way to get the src of an ImageView?

Comment: Please have a look of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

first you need to set tag and then you can surely get the resource of ImageView.

```
   myImageView.setTag(R.drawable.currentImage);    //set this along when you set your image source

    int drawableId = (Integer)myImageView.getTag(); //get the resource
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay, but my image comes from server

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by setting the ImageView description like `.setContentDescription({image_resource})`

and then getting it on appium with

`.getAttribute("name")`

Comment: In recent versions of Appium, you could use `element.getAttribute("contentDescription")` if `element.getAttribute("name")` does not work